NextJS not updating data in production
I am new to Next JS. My Next JS application was working fine on dev environment but as soon as I went to production the get methods are not working meaning its only fetching pre rendered data on build time but not fetching the new entries.
I tried using fetch api with revalidation and no-cache, no-store also I used react tanstack query and swr but still its not fetching new data.
here is my current code
BlogList.jsx page
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import BlogsCard from "@components/BlogsCard";
import toast, { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import Spinner from "@components/Spinner";
import Banner from "@components/Banner";

const BlogList = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const validateEmail = (email) => {
    const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    return emailRegex.test(email);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (!email) {
      toast.error("Please enter an email address.");
      return;
    }

    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
      toast.error("Please enter a valid email address.");
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/newsletter", { email });

      if (response.status === 201) {
        toast.success("Email address subscribed successfully.");
        setEmail("");
      } else {
        toast.error(response.data.error || "Something went wrong. Please try again.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error subscribing email:", error);
      toast.error("Internal Server Error. Please try again later.");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="pt-20 sm:p-0  " >
      <Toaster />
      <div className="p-10">
      <h1 className="font-bold text-2xl sm:text-4xl text-center mt-20 mb-5">Blog</h1>
      <p className="text-center text-normal mb-5 max-w-[400px] m-auto">
        Subscribe for the latest insights, data trends, and best practices to
        grow your ecommerce business.
      </p>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center sm:flex-row flex-col gap-10  ">
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={handleEmailChange}
          className="p-3 rounded-xl border border-black w-full sm:w-auto"
        />
        {loading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <button
            className={`bg-blue-600 rounded-xl px-8 p-3 text-white w-full sm:w-auto ${
              loading ? "opacity-50" : ""
            }`}
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            disabled={loading}
          >
            Subscribe
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <BlogsCard />
      </div>
      <div className="sm:p-5">
         <Banner
           heading={"Get started with new Flywheel 2.0"}
           subHeading={"Advertise your business with superhuman intelligence"}
         />
       </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogList;

BlogsCard.jsx component
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";
import cheerio from "cheerio";

import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const BlogsCard = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleRefresh = () => {
    router.refresh();
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBlogs = async () => {
      try {
        // Fetch data using Axios
        const response = await axios.get("/api/blogs");
        console.log("response is coming", response);
        
        // Check the status code instead of using response.ok
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
    
        // Axios already parses JSON, so you can directly use response.data
        const data = response.data;
        console.log("data is coming", data);
    
        // Sanitize and process the blogs
        const sanitizedBlogs = data.map((blog) => {
          const sanitizedContent = DOMPurify.sanitize(blog.content);
          const $ = cheerio.load(sanitizedContent);
          const firstParagraph = $("p").first().text();
          const limitedContent = firstParagraph.substring(0, 120) + "...";
    
          // Replace backslashes with forward slashes in the image URL
          const correctedImageUrl = blog.imageUrl.replace(/\\/g, "/");
    
          return {
            ...blog,
            imageUrl: correctedImageUrl,
            firstParagraph: limitedContent,
          };
        });
        setBlogs(sanitizedBlogs);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching blogs:", error);
      }
    };
    
  
    fetchBlogs();
  }, []);
  

  return (
    <div className="p-10 sm:p-0 max-w-[1200px] m-auto grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3 gap-20">
      {blogs.map((blog) => (
        <div key={blog._id} className="rounded-lg w-full sm:w-[400px]">
          <div className="relative w-full h-[200px] mb-5">
            <Link href={`/blogs/${blog._id}`}>
              <Image src={blog.imageUrl} className="rounded-t-lg" fill sizes="100vw" />
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="">
            <Link href={`/blogs/${blog._id}`}>
              <h1 className="font-bold text-xl mb-5">{blog.title}</h1>
            </Link>
            <p className="text-normal mb-5">{blog.firstParagraph}</p>
            <p className="font-bold">Author: {blog.author.username}</p>
          </div>
          <button onClick={handleRefresh}>Refresh</button>

        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"

export default BlogsCard;


API Route to get all blogs

import { connectDB } from "@dbConfig/dbConfig";
import Blog from "@models/blogSchema";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  try {
    connectDB();
  
    const blogs = await Blog.find({}).populate("author", "username");
 
    return NextResponse.json(blogs, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching blogs:", error);
    return NextResponse.error("Internal Server Error", { status: 500 });
  }
}


